# Pre-installed GStreamer 0.10 does not recognized the installed element "ladspa-gate"

Tags: 64-bit, plugins, codecs, gstreamer

I am new to gstreamer, and wanted to set it up such that I can explore most plugins (good, bad, ugly, etc.).

I recently started using gstreamer 0.10 and intended to use it to process audio files.

I needed to use "ladspa-gate" which belongs to the GStreamer Bad Plugins 0.10.

Running `gst-launch-0.10 --version` to show what version of gstreamer is preinstalled shows `gst-launch-0.10 version 0.10.36`.

I also ran the following to install `gstreamer-plugins-bad` (not sure if I needed all of them but I just thought it wouldn't hurt to get them all)

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse-dbg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-doc gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-dbg
```

After the installation, I was expecting ladspa-gate to work because it belongs to `gstreamer-plugins-bad` (according to - http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-plugin-ladspa.html), but when I tried running

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location="audio.mp3" ! mad ! ladspa-gate Threshold=-30.0 ! alsasink
```

it resulted in

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "ladspa-gate"
```

After that, I started to look for similar issues on the internet, and tried removing the old registry

```
rm -fv ~/.gstreamer-0.10/registry*
```

It still did not work.

Then I proceeded to run

```
gst-inspect-0.10 ladspa
```

which resulted in

```
Plugin Details:
  Name:                 ladspa
  Description:          All LADSPA plugins
  Filename:             /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstladspa.so
  Version:              0.10.23
  License:              LGPL
  Source module:        gst-plugins-bad
  Source release date:  2012-02-20
  Binary package:       GStreamer Bad Plugins (Ubuntu)
  Origin URL:           https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-bad0.10

  0 features:
```

and `ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstladspa.so` did show that there is such file (`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18920 Apr 15 14:07 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/libgstladspa.so`).

However, if I run `gst-inspect-0.10 | grep ladspa` it shows nothing, which I interpret it as ladspa plugins are not properly setup (maybe even the entire gst plugins bad), therefore is not registered as a ready-for-use plugin.

Another thing probably worth mentioning is that there are two directories under `/usr/lib` which contains gstreamer-0.10 related files, which are `/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-0.10/`; I suspect that `/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/` came from other gstreamer related packages I installed along the path of trying to solve the issue, because my other ubuntu machine does not have such directory, but does have the other directory.

Next thing I might try is doing a fresh install from source, but I hope I don't have to go there. I'd like to avoid unnecessary messing-around.

Answer (score 2):

I made the assumption that there are no other dependencies needed other than the `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` package.

However, I was stupid, and I was wrong.

Running

```
sudo apt-get install ladspa-sdk cmt
rm -fv ~/.gstreamer-0.10/registry*
```

would solve the problem.

Now `gst-inspect-0.10 | grep gate` gives `ladspa:  ladspa-hard-gate: Hard Gate`